# Can I convert a .Net 4.x project/solution to .Net 6 in place

Tags: winforms, .net-6.0

I have a WinForms VB app using .NET 4.x and would like to convert to .NET 6.x. I've seen the "oh, just create a new project/solution" answer. Well, that's easier said than done for me, since my work in .NET is limited. I'm not sure why an existing project can't be converted instead of creating a whole new project/solution. I have tried that but it complains about not having various libraries/assemblies/whatever. It seems that with the app.config and various other config files, MS could create a tool to modify those appropriately instead of someone creating a whole new project/solution. Do they not know what is in their own files? Is upgrading a project/solution so difficult that the only way to do it is to start over?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/#tools-to-assist-porting

Comment: You are right, but the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/#net-upgrade-assistant just was unable to assist successfully in a few cases I have seen. And doing it manually was a kind off "interesting journey" in a way

Comment: Ok, thanks Hans and Stefan. I will check out that page.